# How to create one shortcut for list of commands

Tags: command-line, command, desktop-application, command-prompt

I have two commands which I have to run every time to open an application. How do I create a shortcut for these two commands in one shortcut. Let me give an example:

I have two commands:

1. `D:\spl\v231_CCB\bin>splenviron.cmd -e v231_CCB`
2. `D:\spl\v231_CCB\bin>spl start`

If I want to run the command 1 first and command 2 second then how do I create the shortcut according on my desktop?

Comment: You're looking for an alias, not a shortcut

Comment: i am sorry..may be i misunderstood the name...anyway hope u understand my question mate :)

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java?

Comment: I do, however I don't know the answer. I mean I know how to do aliases in GIT command line, but it's not how it works for Windows command prompt for example.

Comment: I've removed the Java tag. Feel free to add it back if you can explain why it should be there. I've also voted to close because this doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a batch file with this and then click that.

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\spl\v231_CCB\bin"
call splenviron.cmd -e v231_CCB
call spl start
```

The execution of `spl` will depend if `splenviron.cmd` runs and terminates, or keeps running.

Answer (score 1):

```
splenviron.cmd -e v231_CCB && spl start
```

works for windows/ubuntu

If you want a shortcut, you should create a script, bat(windows) or sh(unix) file that will  execute the above command. Or, as other smart people said it already, create an alias for this command :)

Comment: since that splenviron.cmd -e v231_CCB is under D folder, do i have to mention the folder path?

Comment: `&&` is a conditional operator in Windows.  Use `&` alone.